# Upload file not working if checking for uploaded files is on the code

Tags: php, file-upload

The images are uploading normally, but I want an "else if" to check if there is any file selected. This is working:

```
    <?php
session_start();
    include('includes/conexao.php');
    $fileinfo=PATHINFO($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $newFilename=$fileinfo['filename'] ."_". time() . "." . $fileinfo['extension'];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"images/perfis/" . $newFilename);
    $location="images/perfis/" . $newFilename;

$todas_fotos = mysqli_query($conexao, "select * FROM esc_usuarios_fotos WHERE img_usu_codigo = '" . $_SESSION['codigo'] . "'");

if( mysqli_num_rows($todas_fotos) > 0) {
        //$path=$location;
        //if(unlink($path)) echo "Deleted file ";
        mysqli_query($conexao,"UPDATE esc_usuarios_fotos SET img_local = '$location' WHERE img_usu_codigo = '" . $_SESSION['codigo'] . "'");
}
else if( mysqli_num_rows($todas_fotos) == 0)
{
        mysqli_query($conexao,"insert into esc_usuarios_fotos (img_local, img_usu_codigo) values ('$location', '" . $_SESSION['codigo'] . "')");
}
else {

};
    header('location:perfil.php');
?>
```

It inserts if there isn't an image, but if there is, it updates. But when I add:

```
else if (empty($_FILES['image']['name']))
{
header('location:perfil.php');
}
```

It returns me undefined index: extension on line 5. How to go?

Comment: first of all check `print_r($_FILES)` you will get the solution.

Comment: sorry, kinda newbie, how to do that?

Comment: write this after session start

Comment: there you go: "Array ( [image] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) ) 
Notice: Undefined index: extension on line 6", i don't even...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the code as follows. Here we are checking whether the file is not available at the beginning of the code and redirect if no file is found.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (empty($_FILES['image']['name']))
{
  header('location:perfil.php?error=1');
  return;
}
include('includes/conexao.php');
$fileinfo=PATHINFO($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$newFilename=$fileinfo['filename'] ."_". time() . "." . $fileinfo['extension'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"images/perfis/" . $newFilename);
$location="images/perfis/" . $newFilename;

$todas_fotos = mysqli_query($conexao, "select * FROM esc_usuarios_fotos WHERE 
img_usu_codigo = '" . $_SESSION['codigo'] . "'");

if( mysqli_num_rows($todas_fotos) > 0) {
    //$path=$location;
    //if(unlink($path)) echo "Deleted file ";
    mysqli_query($conexao,"UPDATE esc_usuarios_fotos SET img_local = '$location' WHERE img_usu_codigo = '" . $_SESSION['codigo'] . "'");
 }else {
    mysqli_query($conexao,"insert into esc_usuarios_fotos (img_local, img_usu_codigo) values ('$location', '" . $_SESSION['codigo'] . "')");
 }
```

and in the perfil.php you should put

window.onload = function(){
     var url = new URL(window.location.href);
     var error = url.searchParams.get("error");
     if(error==1)
        alert("No file uploaded");

}

Comment: This did the trick! Just one more question, where can I put a little script to show an alert that no files were selected?

Comment: this is perfect

Comment: i have tried using  $message = "Você não selecionou uma imagem!";
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>"; after the header, but didn't worked at all

Comment: @LuannSousa I should provide it as a separate code segment. I don't know whether we can submit it as another answer. The code perfil.php should be modified here

Comment: No you cannot echo anything before or after header redirection

Comment: @RinsadAhmed Oh, I see, any idea of where should i put the script?

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: @RinsadAhmed it shows the error on url, but there is no alert

Comment: Edited please check

Comment: @RinsadAhmed You are a savior! Thank you very much!